# Highcharts: set 'select' state on a point and maintain it after mouseover?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts and trying to set the `select` state on a point and maintain the state.

I can set the state just fine, like this:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
chart.get('b').setState('select');
```

But the state gets unset when the user mouses over and then out of the point.

Here is a JSFiddle example - try mousing over the red point and observe that it loses its `select` state: http://jsfiddle.net/o72xgtfm/1/

Shouldn't the state be maintained even after mouseover, given that it's a `select` state, not `hover`?

All I want is to set the point as red, and keep it red. Could I perhaps set a custom state that wouldn't be affected by mouseover?

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix this eventually by using:

```
point.select(true, true);
```

rather than

```
point.setState('select');
```

The latter is undocumented, whereas the first seems to be the official way to do things.

Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#select

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the state is simply changed to `hover` and as long as you don't set it up back, it is not returned. Everything as it should be.

What you can do is tracking `mouseout` event on that point and assign the state again. But it will be blinking from red to grey to red.

What I propose is avoid using states for this purpose. I do not know your business case but if it is only about the point color, you can explicitly add it to the point without states at all:

```
    data: [
        {'id': 'a', 'x': 185.4, 'y': 66.8}, 
        {'id': 'b', 'x': 177.8, 'y': 75.5, color: "red" }, 
        {'id': 'c', 'x': 180.3, 'y': 93.2}
    ]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o72xgtfm/4/)

Comment: Thanks. I want to let the user highlight a point by selecting from a drop down list, and for it to stay highlighted while the user mouses around elsewhere in the chart. Having to update the colour manually and redraw the chart seems messy, but if it's the only way :-/

Comment: one further question: how can I bind a `mouseout` event to my `point` variable? trying `point.on('mouseover', function() {... });` but getting an error.... looking at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point it seems there may be no way to bind a mouseout event to an individual point?