# Highcharts: why does redrawing change the radius of the selected point?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a similar, but different problem to [Highcharts: set 'select' state on a point and maintain it after mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623787/highcharts-set-select-state-on-a-point-and-maintain-it-after-mouseover)

This relates to what happens to the rendering of the point after a `redraw` event, not a `mouseover` event.

I have set a particular point in a scatter chart to have the 'select' state:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
chart.get('b').setState('select');
```

And I have also defined the `select` state as follows in the chart options:

```
 select: {
   radius: 8,
   enabled: true,
   lineColor: 'red',
   fillColor: 'red'
}
```

The point is red and has a radius of 8, as you can see in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o72xgtfm/3/

However, when I run `redraw` on the chart, the colour stays the same (so the `select` state is still clearly maintained on the point, i.e. [this question is not a duplicate of my other question about `select` state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623787/highcharts-set-select-state-on-a-point-and-maintain-it-after-mouseover)) but the radius reduces.

Why? And how can I get the radius to stay set at 8 on this point?

Comment: have updated question to make clear it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Really unclear why my answer has been deleted without any explanation. Won't this be helpful for other people Googling for the same thing? I only added the answer because I wanted to help people! And as previously noted, *this is not not a duplicate question*. I use StackOverflow because it's useful for everyone: aggressively marking non-duplicates and duplicates, and deleting answers, makes the site worse.

Comment: I agree that this is technically not a duplicate, though I had to read very closely to see that it's not the case (and even then, I'd think it's up for debate). I've voted to re-open. I do think it's wise to rollback your latest edit, or at least change your comment to explain "how this question is different from the other one" (as opposed to voicing opinion about the process, which is better left to comments or a meta post).

Comment: Thanks. Have edited (for the third time) to make it clear that it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is because point.setState('select') is different than point.select(true).

As you pointed out point.select() is part of API and it is working - http://jsfiddle.net/o72xgtfm/5/

In fact part of point.select() code is point.setState('select'), but it also sets attribute of point - 'selected' to true and in point.options.selected to true.

```
select: function (selected, accumulate) {
        var point = this,
            series = point.series,
            chart = series.chart;

        selected = pick(selected, !point.selected);

        // fire the event with the defalut handler
        point.firePointEvent(selected ? 'select' : 'unselect', { accumulate: accumulate }, function () {
            point.selected = point.options.selected = selected;
            series.options.data[inArray(point, series.data)] = point.options;

            point.setState(selected && SELECT_STATE);

            // unselect all other points unless Ctrl or Cmd + click
            if (!accumulate) {
                each(chart.getSelectedPoints(), function (loopPoint) {
                    if (loopPoint.selected && loopPoint !== point) {
                        loopPoint.selected = loopPoint.options.selected = false;
                        series.options.data[inArray(loopPoint, series.data)] = loopPoint.options;
                        loopPoint.setState(NORMAL_STATE);
                            loopPoint.firePointEvent('unselect');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    },
```

Knowing this it is possible to call point.setState('select') with same effects - http://jsfiddle.net/o72xgtfm/6/

```
chart.get('b').setState('select');
chart.get('b').selected = true;
chart.get('b').options.selected = true;
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same exact issue OP had except instead of the `select` state I am trying to use the `inactive` state after redraw. I know I am successfully setting the state to `inactive` however the styles/properties I set for that state are not being reflected after redraw.  Is there a similar solution for the `inactive` state?

Comment: @JakeZeitz Only `select` can be set in series data because only that state is checked in Highcharts code when points are created (init or update). You would have to set the state again after the redraw or modify/hack the Highcharts code like in this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d906guno/1/ Your comment could be a question IMO, so if you have anything else to add to this conversation please consider opening a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this eventually by using:

```
point.select(true, true);
```

rather than

```
point.setState('select');
```

The latter is undocumented, whereas the first seems to be the official way to do things.